# How to list repositories/catalog in IBM Container Registery?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Container Registry and trying to list the repositories/catalog using the below command.

```
curl -i https://us.icr.io/v2/_catalog
HTTP/2 401 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://us.icr.io/oauth/token",service="registry",scope="registry:catalog:*",error="invalid_token"
```

The `www-authenticate` field state that the scope of the token should be `registry:catalog:*`.

When I tried to create a token with this scope, the generated token provides an empty access list.

Running the command with above generated access token gives the below error:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://us.icr.io/v2/_catalog
HTTP/2 403 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://us.icr.io/oauth/token",service="registry",scope="registry:catalog:*",error="insufficient_scope"
date: Mon, 23 May 2022 16:53:38 GMT
content-length: 134
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; form-action 'none';
docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
x-registry-supports-signatures: 1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
server: IBM Cloud Container Registry

{"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"insufficient scope","detail":[{"Type":"registry","Class":"","Name":"catalog","Action":"*"}]}]}
```

Does IBM Container Registry support [`_catalog` docker v2 api](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-repositories)?

Are there any other way to list the repositories?

Note: I have tried `https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/container-registry#list-images`, it lists all the images but not the repositories like [`_catalog` docker v2 api](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-repositories).

Comment: Most cloud registries don't support this API because it doesn't distinguish between different customers.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IBM Cloud Container Registry documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-registry_overview#docker) and the experience you made, that API is not supported.

> IBM Cloud Container Registry supports Docker Engine v17.07, or later.

Docker itself defines the Engine API, Hub API and the Registry API. The latter has the function you asked for.